# Why is my bootstrap carousel not working in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I have installed jquery and bootrap using `npm install jquery --save` and `npm install bootstrap --save` and they are found in the `node_modules`. I added the scripts to my angular.json file under `"scripts"` as following:

```
"scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]
```

Here is my component.html file:

```
<div  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/grey.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/grey.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/grey.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Here is my component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Edit: Now I have added bootstrap into my angular.json file under `scripts` as well as suggested by Raj below but it is still not working.

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
]
```

Comment: I use `console.log($('.carousel').carousel)` is undefined, so... I move bootstrap.js and jquery.js to assets and import  in index.html, It's can `console.log` that, but still can't use in app.component. I thought it's wired.

Comment: I test that way import in `index.html` can work, but the animation not work!

Comment: @LiHao that could work I can try that... what do you mean by you move bootstrap and jquery .js to assets? Are you talking about the node_modules files?

Comment: I found the reason, please use bootstrap v4.0.0, v4.5.0 can't work in chrome even the official demo is, use v4.0.0 css and js and import in index.html, it's work!

Comment: @LiHao THanks so much I didnt think of that! How can i change now? Can I delete the bootstrap file in node_modules and install the 4.0.0 version? Or will it cause errors?

Comment: Update: Im using `npm uninstall bootstrap --no-save`

Comment: you can just install the old version, I thought npm can override `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 jquery@3.3.1 --save`

Comment: @LiHao Yeah I didn't know that and I was worried it will corrupt the file or cause errors as im still new to angular, thanks! It works now thanks! Please copy this and paste as an answer so I can accept your answer if you want credit

Comment: ok, thx! I hope Bootstrap can fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `boostrap v4.0.0`, After `v4.1.0` `carousel` can't work on a lot of browser, even official demo page can't work.

Install and import in angular.json.

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0 jquery@3.3.1 --save
```

```
"styles": [
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss",
 "src/styles.scss"
]
```

```
"scripts": [
 "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add *bootstrap.css* in your *angular.json* under the "styles" tag

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
          "src/styles.css"              
        ],
```

Comment: @argonx Can you try using the "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
Not that, I removed "./" from the original answer

Comment: Ok I tried `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/scss/bootstrap.scss"` now still not working... (by the way I typed scss because my project and it's files are in scss)

Answer (score 0):

I think better thing to use is NGX-bootstrap components in angular.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

Comment: For this task, I'm required to use bootstrap and add it to script using exactly `"scripts": [
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ]` but I will look into that for other projects

Comment: i think you need to include these script where angular compiles them not right in components.

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/  this is good resource for your purpose

Comment: Yes that's why I added it to angular.json, I didn't add it to the component now I'm wondering if I should as well

Comment: I will check out that link